# gtkentry focus behaviour

Tags: gtk, gtkd, gtkentry

Is there any existing mechanism for a GtkEntry to simply position the cursor at the end of the text when focused, rather than selecting its contents to be overwritten by the next key? It seems odd to have to add a signal handler to do something this basic, but I can't find anything in the properties.

**Edit:** The signal handler doesn't work; whatever I do the default behaviour gets triggered *after* my handler runs. Here's my gtkd code; note that I am appending some text in the focus-in-event handler, and the appended text gets selected as well:

```
class NoteView : Entry
{
  this(string text) {
    if (text) {
      setText(text);
    }
    setEditable(true);
    setCanFocus(true);

    addOnFocusIn(delegate bool(GdkEventFocus* f, Widget w) {
        // clear selection
        selectRegion(0, 0);
        // test to see whether the appended text gets selected too
        appendText("hello");
        setPosition(-1);
        // don't let any other handlers run
        return 1;
      }, ConnectFlags.AFTER);
  }
}
```

The `addOnFocusIn` method is in the gtkd Gtk.Widget api; it calls `g_signal_connect_data` internally, which should in theory be honouring the `G_CONNECT_AFTER` flag I'm passing it, but doesn't seem to be.

**Edit2:** Solved - the `grab-focus` handler was doing the text selection, and being handled after `focus-in-event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out GtkEntry was selecting the text on the `grab-focus` signal, not `focus-in-event`. Working code:

```
class NoteView : Entry
{
  this(string text) {
    if (text) {
      setText(text);
    }
    setEditable(true);
    setCanFocus(true);
    setHasFrame(false);

    addOnGrabFocus(delegate void(Widget w) {
        selectRegion(0, 0);
        setPosition(-1);
      }, ConnectFlags.AFTER);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't find anything in the docs.

I guess they figured that diverging from the default behavior is that uncommon that they just let people do it with signals, rather than provide a property for it.

Consider creating a subclass of `GtkEntry` that exhibits the behavior you require.